# VBA Auto Update Pivot Table

Tags: vba, pivot-table

I have a pivot table in sheet 2. The pivot table filter will automatically change each time I change the value in sheet 1 cell D1. However, the table only refreshes when I go back to sheet 2 and click anywhere on screen. How can I get this to change automatically?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'Set the Variables to be used
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim NewCat As String

'Set worksheet and cell
Set pt = Worksheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Sum1")
NewCat = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").Value

'Update and refresh
With pt
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
pt.Update
End With

End Sub
```

Note: I have also tried pt.Refresh and pt.RefreshTable